# Error al tratar de insert datos en tabla (Trigger)

Tags: sql, oracle, trigger

Soy nuevo aquí y vengo para preguntarles dónde se encuentra el error en el código (exact match returns..) ya que me estoy comiendo la cabeza y sigo sin encontrarlo. Resulta que el Trigger funciona con las dos primeras inserciones en la tabla Convocatoria pero en la tercera me devuelve el error que dejo abajo. Quiero que el trigger me controle esta restricción: El año de la fecha de cierre de la convocatoria tiene que ser superior en una unidad al año de la fecha de cierre de dicha convocatoria. Muchas gracias!

```
CREATE TABLE ALUMNO_US(
OID_AL  number(8)   NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
dni         CHAR(9) NOT NULL CHECK (LENGTH(dni)=9),
nombre      VARCHAR2(50) ,
apellido    VARCHAR2(50) ,
email       VARCHAR2(50) check (email LIKE '%@%'),
telefono    INTEGER,
fechaNacimiento DATE
);


CREATE TABLE CONVOCATORIA(
    OID_CON number(8) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    numero  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    tipo    VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    fechaApertura DATE,
    fechaCierre   DATE,
    CONSTRAINT chk_fechaCierre check(fechaCierre > fechaApertura),
    OID_AL  number(8),
    OID_AC number(8),
    FOREIGN KEY (OID_AL) REFERENCES ALUMNO_US ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (OID_AC) REFERENCES ALUMNOSCONVOCATORIA ON DELETE CASCADE
     );
```

////////BORRADO DE DATOS DE TABLAS Y CREACIÓN DE TRIGGER///////

```
delete alumno_us;
delete convocatoria;

create or replace trigger fechaCon
after insert  ON convocatoria
declare
fechaA number;
fechaC number;
begin
select extract(year from fechaApertura) into fechaA from convocatoria;
select extract(year from fechaCierre) into fechaC from convocatoria;

if (fechaC != fechaA + 1)
then raise_application_error (-20600, ' El año de la fecha de cierre de la convocatoria tiene que ser superior en una unidad al año de la fecha de cierre de dicha convocatoria');
end if;
end;
/
alter trigger fechaCon enable;
```

/////INSERCIÓN DE TABLAS//////

```
insert into alumno_us values ('1', '897453621', 'Paco', 'Burro', 'paco@gmail.com','786765123', to_date('03/03/1997','DD/MM/YYYY'));
insert into alumno_us values ('2', '897453621', 'Paco', 'Burro', 'paco@gmail.com','786765123', to_date('03/03/1998','DD/MM/YYYY'));
insert into alumno_us values ('3', '89745321', 'Paco', 'Burro', 'paco@gmail.com','786765123', to_date('03/03/1999','DD/MM/YYYY'));
insert into convocatoria values ('1', '78123', 'ERASMUS', to_date('09/12/1999','DD/MM/YYYY'),to_date('12/12/2001','DD/MM/YYYY'),'1', null);
insert into convocatoria values ('2', '78123', 'ERASMUS', to_date('11/12/1999','DD/MM/YYYY'),to_date('12/12/2000','DD/MM/YYYY'),'2', null);
insert into convocatoria values ('3', '78122', 'TRAINING', to_date('10/12/1995','DD/MM/YYYY'),to_date('12/12/2002','DD/MM/YYYY'),'3', null);
```

///LOG///

```
3 filas eliminado


0 filas eliminado


Trigger FECHACON compilado


Trigger FECHACON alterado.


1 fila insertadas.


1 fila insertadas.


1 fila insertadas.


Error que empieza en la línea: 22 del comando :
insert into convocatoria values ('1', '78123', 'ERASMUS', to_date('09/12/1999','DD/MM/YYYY'),to_date('12/12/2001','DD/MM/YYYY'),'1', null)
Informe de error -
ORA-20600:  El año de la fecha de cierre de la convocatoria tiene que ser superior en una unidad al año de la fecha de cierre de dicha convocatoria
ORA-06512: at "PRUEBAS.FECHACON", line 9
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'PRUEBAS.FECHACON'


1 fila insertadas.


Error que empieza en la línea: 24 del comando :
insert into convocatoria values ('3', '78122', 'TRAINING', to_date('10/12/1995','DD/MM/YYYY'),to_date('12/12/2002','DD/MM/YYYY'),'3', null)
Informe de error -
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at "PRUEBAS.FECHACON", line 5
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'PRUEBAS.FECHACON'
```

El OID_AC está a null porque no he creado otra tabla, que no es necesaria para comprobar el correcto funcionamiento del trigger

Comment: Fallan los dos insert que no cumplen con la condicion que pusiste. No entiendo tu pregunta.

Comment: Hola gbianchi, ante todo gracias por responder. El fallo 'El año de la fecha de cierre de la convocatoria tiene que ser superior en una unidad al año de la fecha de cierre de dicha convocatoria' se debe producir (según el trigger) cada vez que el año de apertura y cierre difieran en más de una unidad. Como puedes ver en el log, la primera inserción en convocatoria no cumple esta propiedad y genera dicho fallo, la segunda inserción cumple la propiedad y se inserta la fila correctamente pero la tercera inserción no cumple la propiedad y se genera un fallo distinto al del trigger y no sé por qué.

Comment: Sé que es algo del trigger pero he probado de todo y aún no me salen todas las inserciones correctamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este trigger es after insert. Por lo tanto la tabla ya tiene los datos insertados.

```
begin
select extract(year from fechaApertura) into fechaA from convocatoria;
select extract(year from fechaCierre) into fechaC from convocatoria;
```

Estas dos lineas, devuelven un valor desde la tabla convocatoria. En el primer caso, la tabla tiene solo un registro por lo tanto anda. 
Pero al hacer el segundo insert correcto, la tabla ya tiene mas de un registro, por lo tanto ese select no devuelve un solo valor, si no que devuelve todos los de la tabla.

A esos select le falta un where para saber cual fue el registro que insertaste recientemente.

Deberias agregar en el where algo como

```
where OID_CON = :new.OID_CON
```

Comment: Exactamente pensé en algo de eso pero el caso es que no se me ocurre nada para poner detrás del where

Comment: ahi edite la respuesta

Comment: Lo estuve probando con otros OID pero nunca lo hice con el de Convocatoria. Muchas gracias amigo, ya funciona correctamente!